# Need to Back Up a MacBook that Won't Turn On

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, backup

I have a Retina MacBook Pro running El Capitan. Recently, the machine refuses to let me log in. After booting and entering my password, the Mac starts loading, but freezes once the loading bar is full.

With Apple Support, I tried booting in several different modes, restarting things, etc. I was unable to login or see anything other than loading screens. So, they had me book an appointment for the Genius Bar.

I am wondering if there is anyway to back up a Mac in this state. I have Googled and searched this forum, but all the methods require some functionality on the device that needs to be backed up. If I can't back it up, so be it, I just wanted to check as it has some very important files.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Please add some additional info such as the model year or number as well as the software version.  This will help others as they try to assist you. - From Review -

Answer (score 1):

Can you restart into Recovery HD? If you can, then you should be able to copy the HD onto an external HD using Disk Utility.

If you can't do that, but have another Mac available, you can restart into Target Disk Mode, and connect the two Macs together using a Thunderbolt cable. On the other Mac, your HD will show up as an external HD, and you'll be able to back it up.

Comment: Ok, I think I can reboot it in Target Disk Mode.
My working Mac is a mid-2010, so has no Thunderbolt. If I get a Thunderbolt cable and a Thunderbolt to Firewire Adapter, that should work?

Comment: @albertshoes I believe so. On older models Target Disk Mode used FireWire.

Comment: [This page](http://www.apple.com/shop/question/answers/product/MD464LL/A/will-this-allow-users-to-start-a-thunderboltequipped-mac-in-target-disk-mode-and-access-it-via-a-firewireonly-mac/Q9PAJJDY9A77J9HFP) on Apple's confirms that using a Thunderbolt cable with a Firewire adapter lets the machines communicate successfully, albeit obviously at the reduced Firewire throughput speed.